# Carriage returns in CSV

Tags: php, csv, carriage-return

The [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function doesn't understand `\r` (CR) as a valid line separator. Is there a way around this or should I write my own parser?

EDIT: This fixes it:

[Read in text file line by line php - newline not being detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817783/read-in-text-file-line-by-line-php-newline-not-being-detected)

Comment: Are you using '\r' or "\r"...basically quotes difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the [auto_detect_line_endings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, found it in another answer also. `fgets` suffers the same problem. The CSV is generate by Excel 2011, and it thinks it's a good idea to default to `CR` when on a Mac.