# what is the best way to read a text file avoiding text editor issue in php?

Tags: php

The code below are working, but! when the sample text file was edited in other version of text editor.. 
**it wont!!**

**What is the very best way to read text line by line without the text editor issue using php??**

**sample text file**
name - john              (line 0)
age - 24                 (line 1)
gender - male            (line 2)
message - "the message"  (line 3)

**code**

```
        $result = "";
        $lines = file('sample.txt'); 

        $name= $lines[0];
        $age= $lines[1];
        $gender= $lines[2];
        $message = $lines[3];       

        echo $mail_to;
        echo $port_num;
        echo $phone_num;
        echo $message;
```

i want to put each line in a variable for a reason...
**on my notepad++  View->Show Symbol->Show All Charactes**
each line appeared **"CR LF"**... but when the other user edited the text file; all line change into **"CR"** only....

Can PHP handle this issue???

Comment: Im not 100% sure what you want a(n) answer(s) to?

Comment: maybe my issue is familiar with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817783/read-in-text-file-line-by-line-php-newline-not-being-detected?rq=1

Comment: But I am newbie on php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read a plain text file with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103287/read-a-plain-text-file-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$handle = fopen("sample.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $infos;
    $i = 0;
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $info[i++] = $line;
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo $info[0];
    echo $info[1];
    echo $info[2];
    echo $info[3];
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

from related question: [How to read a file line by line in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246597/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-php)

Comment: Is there any php configuration like ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);