# How to load the data into html table from a text file

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to display the upload.txt records into a html table.

The upload.txt file is located at this url : http://localhost:3000/upload.  When we call this url it will get upload.txt file.

Actually I'm using node.js here.So I'm routing here like this :

```
app.get('/upload', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('views/upload.txt');
});
```

My upload.txt :

```
client_ip
1.0.230.145
1.1.145.219
1.1.214.239
1.11.112.100
1.112.218.165
1.112.98.44
1.113.55.77
1.114.193.160
1.115.77.221
1.115.81.190
1.124.150.22
1.124.158.81
```

My table.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color:#FFBD0C;
}


table {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:1px;
    background:#CCC;
        margin-right:200px
    }

table th {
        background:#EEE;
        font-weight:600;
        padding:10px 20px;
        text-align:center;
    }

table tbody {
        padding:0; margin:0;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border-spacing:0px;
    }
table td {
          background:#C7DBED;
          padding:5px 10px;
          text-align:center;
    }


</style>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
var userListData = [];

$(document).ready(function() {

    populateTable();

});

function populateTable() {

    var tableContent = '';


    $.get( 'http://localhost:3000/upload', function( data ) {

      alert(data); // Here I'm able to get the entire text file data.
        $.each(data, function(){
           alert(data); // here I'm unable to get the data.
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.client_ip + '</td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });


        $('#tablediv').html(tableContent);
    });
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 style="color:brown; margin-left:490px;margin-top:150px;">Upload Clients</h2>
<table  width="60%" id="tab" style="margin-left:200px;">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Clients</th>
  </tr>
<thead>
<tbody id="tablediv">
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

At this point,how can we load the client_ip values into the table.

```
function populateTable() {

    var tableContent = '';


    $.get( 'http://localhost:3000/upload', function( data ) {

      alert(data);
        $.each(data, function(){
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.client_ip + '</td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });


        $('#tablediv').html(tableContent);
    });
};
```

Actually I'm unable to load the data into a html table.Can anyone please help me out regarding this issue.

Comment: LOCAL HOST LINKS WILL NOT WORK ONLINE...Don't post them here!

Comment: your url says `http://localhost:3000/upload` in `$.get`. Shouldn't you be specifying complete `url` with extension like `$.get('http://localhost:3000/upload.txt'...`?

Comment: Actually I'm using node.js in my code.What I'm trying to say is if suppose the text file is in the server at one url then how to load the text file data into a html table.

Comment: if your upload directory is `http://localhost:3000/upload` what are you trying to read from `http://localhost:3000/uploadcsv` in your script

Comment: Your `$.each` will not work.. once you get `data` as response try logging by using `console.log(data)` in console and see how it is obtained

Comment: Actually I'm using node.js,So, http://localhost:3000/upload this url is just a route .In this route I'm redirecting to upload.txt like this            app.get('/upload', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('views/upload.txt');
});

Comment: in that case change `$.get( 'http://localhost:3000/uploadcsv', function( data ) {` to `$.get( 'http://localhost:3000/upload', function( data ) {` in your script

Comment: Are you getting the file? Is it hitting server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read in text file line by line php - newline not being detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817783/read-in-text-file-line-by-line-php-newline-not-being-detected)

Comment: Actually $.each is not working.I'm unable to get the data after $.each.But before $.each I'm able to get the data.

Comment: Ya I'm getting the file .It is hitting the server

Comment: `console.log(data)` in success and see what you are getting? Or what you are getting in `alert(data)`

Comment: $.get( 'http://localhost:3000/upload', function( data ) {

      alert(data);  //Here I'm getting the entire text file data
        $.each(data, function(){
       console.log(data); //Here I'm unable to get the data
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.client_ip + '</td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });

Comment: What is that.. Please post what you get in `data` as response

Comment: @GangiguntaDivya can you update the question with what you can see with alert(data) or console.log(data)??

Comment: Through console.log(data), I'm not getting any data.But through alert(data) I'm getting data like this,client-ip
1.0.230.145
1.1.145.219
1.1.214.239
1.11.112.100
1.112.218.165
1.112.98.44
1.113.55.77
1.114.193.160
1.115.77.221
1.115.81.190
1.124.150.22
1.124.158.81

Comment: if you are using firebug then in console select `All` tab to see the data in console. and you are getting data as object . am i right ? or just string

Comment: In firebug ,I'm able to get the data using console.log(data) but before $.each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not trying to read file line by line try this instead:

```
function populateTable() {

    var tableContent = '';


    $.get( 'http://localhost:3000/upload', function( data ) {

      alert(data);
      //this will split the string into array line by line
      var lineByline = data.split('\n');
        //here we're itraing the array which you've created and printing the values
        $.each(lineByline , function(key,value){
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });

        $('#tablediv').html(tableContent);
    });
};
```

For efficiency you can try loading the file in chunks somthing like:

```
    //telling your ajax to read only some amount of data
    // you have to use this in recursion to get the entire data 
    // just add this before you call $.get(..)
    $.ajaxSetup({ beforeSend : function(xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=0-2800" );
    }});
```

Comment: Through this code,I'm able to display a table but rows are filled with numbers starting from Zero.I want to display the client_ip's in the table instead of numbers.

Comment: Ya,now its working fine.Thanks a lot for ur info.But it is taking time to load the client_ip's .Actually I have nearly 68000 records in the upload.txt file

Comment: After using the $.ajaxSetup  code,I'm able to get the client_ip's only within that range.How to combine all the chunks finally to display all the client_ip's.Can we able to keep a dynamic range instead of using a static range

Comment: @GangiguntaDivya use a `recursion` over that and you should get all the data

Comment: k fine.Thank u very much.

Answer (score 2):

First problem seems to be the ajax request is not able to find the resource. 
The ajax source URL is missing the file extension. i.e.
"http://localhost:3000/upload"

Data is obtained. Your implemented alert pops up with the data once you add the file extension. But he problem seems to be with the $.each loop

You can update your populateTable function with the below one

```
function populateTable() {

    var tableContent = '';

    $.get('http://localhost:3000/upload.txt', function(data) {
       alert(data);
       $('#tablediv').html(data.replace('n',''));
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/9nxoeaqu/)**

I assume you are getting it back as `string`. Then you need to `split` the `string` on based on `space` character and then loop it and also need to avoid first string which will `client_ip`

```
var ips=data.split(' ');
var tableContent;
$.each(ips, function(key,value){
    if(key==0) //do not display client_ip which is first string
        return;
    tableContent += '<tr>';
    tableContent += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
    tableContent += '</tr>';

});
$('table').html(tableContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some update to my pervious answer

This would handle your requirement to the best

```
function populateTable() {

    var tableContent = '';


    $.get( 'http://localhost:3000/upload.txt', function( data ) {

      alert(data);
      var lineByline = data.split('\n')
        $.each(lineByline , function(index,value){
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });


        $('#tablediv').html(tableContent);
    });
};
```