# how to list data to table

Tags: jquery

I have a button and when that button is clicked the content of this file will list them to a table. Can some give me an idea how to do this? TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load the data into html table from a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006410/how-to-load-the-data-into-html-table-from-a-text-file)

Comment: okay thankyou for enlightening me, I've been searching for it yesterday I couldn't find. Thanks @SaravananSachi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code,

```
<table id="listHere">

</table>
```

You cannot access the file from your local system. Place the text file on your server.

```
var txtData = new Array();
$.get('passwords.txt', function (data) {
    txtData = data.split('\n');
    var htmTable = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < txtData.length; i++) {
        htmTable = htmTable + "<tr><td>" + txtData[i] + "</td></tr>";
    }
    $('#listHere').append(htmTable);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tableContent = '';


$.get( 'file path', function( data ) {

  //this will split the string into array line by line
  var lineByline = data.split('\n');
    //here we're itraing the array which you've created and printing the values
    $.each(lineByline , function(key,value){
        tableContent += '<tr>';
        tableContent += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
        tableContent += '</tr>';
    });

    $('#listHere').html(tableContent);
});
```